# How to wrap API responses to handle success and error based on Clean Architecture?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, clean-architecture

What is the approach to wrapping responses from the server and then process? The API is returning responses in the following format:

**SUCCESS:**

```
 {
   "data": [],
   "statusCode": 200,
   "statusMessage": "Operation success",
   "success": true
 }
```

**FAILURE:**

```
  {
    "errors": [],
    "statusCode": 500,
    "statusMessage": "Something went wrong",
    "success": false
  }
```

I'm trying to apply Clean Architecture principles to my application and I want to know how can I wrap the responses to better handle errors?

Answer (score 0):

1. fillCities() calls getCities()
2. getCities() calls getCityList()
3. getCities processes the response that comes from getCityList endpoint through funcErrorCheckAndTransform and returns back an observable to presenter layer

   ```
   fun <T> funcErrorCheckAndTransform(): (BaseResponse<T>) -> Observable<T> {
     return { response ->
       if (response.isSuccess) {
         Observable.just(response.data)
       } else {
         val e = Exception(response.errorMsg)
         Timber.e(e)
         Observable.error(e)
       }
     }
   }



   override fun getCities(): Observable<out Cities> {
     return locationService.getCityList()
         .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
         .flatMap(funcErrorCheckAndTransform())
         .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
   }



    @GET("getcitylist")
    fun getCityList():
        Observable<BaseResponse<ProfileResponse.Cities>>



     override fun fillCities(defaultCityName: String?) {
       view.showProgress(R.string.cities_are_getting_dialog_message)
       compositeDisposable.add(
           interactor.getCities().subscribe(
               {
                 view.hideProgress()
                 view.fetchCities(it, defaultCityName)
               },
               { error ->
                 view.onError(error)
               }
           ))
     }
   ```

Comment: I have looked a couple examples and they all use Observable which I understand is RxJava, I have not worked with RxJava, Is it necessary that start learning it or could I get by without it for now?