# Handling error and success response from API using Android Clean Architechture

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java, clean-architecture

I'm trying to implement Clean Architecture in my app. My API sends response in success and failure cases as:

```
{
   "data": [],
   "statusCode": 200,
   "statusMessage": "success",
   "success": true
 }
```

OR

```
{
    "statusCode": xxx,
    "statusMessage": "Invalid Details",
    "success": false
  }
```

In the previous approach I used Retrofit and `BaseResponse` POJO class to handle the data scenarios, but in my current app I'm using Clean Architecture with RxJava & Retrofit.

I will get one of **Observable**, **Flowable** or **Single** as response but with `BaseResponse` as type.

```
data class BaseResponse<T>(
    @SerializedName("status") val status: Boolean,
    @SerializedName("statuscode") val statusCode: Int? = null,
    @SerializedName("message") val message: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("data") val data: T? = null
)
```

I'm checking Rx Error in Domain using Rx with custom RESULT as success or failure for all:

```
fun <T> Single<T>.toResult(): Single<Result<T>> = this
.map { Result.Success(it) as Result<T> }
.onErrorReturn {
    Result.Failure(
        if (it is CompositeException) it.exceptions.last().toView()
        else it.toView()
    )
}
```

but for handling Dynamic Response I'm not able wrap them.

I tried the approach mentioned in 
[How to wrap API responses to handle success and error based on Clean Architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51608002/how-to-wrap-api-responses-to-handle-success-and-error-based-on-clean-architectur) and couple of others, but none of them worked out.

How to wrap the items either in usecases / repository or in Data layer and pass them to presentation like `data` as Result.success or `statusMessage` as Result.Error

Comment: you can write a custom json deserializer which will check `statusCode` and return appropriate `Result`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `data` in your JSON response is null , you can just ignore the `<T>` in Base Response and can use `Either<A, B>` custom class in case of Success or failure.

U can create [Custom Either](https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-return-an-either-error-data-with-a-centralised-error-handler-on-android-72efdaf88cca) as mentioned in [here](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture-Kotlin/blob/master/app/src/main/kotlin/com/fernandocejas/sample/core/functional/Either.kt)

so in your Repository code looks like

```
fun getMyList(): Single<Either<BaseModel, CustomModel?>> =
    apiClient.getList()
        .map {
            if (it.status.equals("success")) {
                Either.Success(it.data?.toEntity())
            } else {
                Either.Failure(it.toEntity())
            }
        }

fun <T> BaseResponse<T>.toEntity() = BaseModel(
    status = status,
    statusCode = statusCode,
    message = message
)
```

Same goes with your CustomResponse.toEntity to CustomModel , However you are doing `Single<T>.toResult()` so in your Presentation layer , you can check like

```
.subscribe({ result ->
   when (result) {
     is Result.Success -> result.data.successOrFailure(::hanldeError, ::handleSuccess)
     is Result.Failure -> {}
   }
},{})
```

and do your operations in `hanldeError()` and `handleSuccess()` respectively